# "Dining Philosophers" using Fututre in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I am trying to solve Philosopher Problem using Future  in Java.

```
 public class Philo implements Callable<PhiloStatus> {

    private PhiloStatus status;
    private Philo leftPhilo;
    private Philo rightPhilo;

    private String name;

    public Philo(String name) {
        status = PhiloStatus.THINKING;

        this.name =name;
    }



    public void setLeftPhilo(Philo leftPhilo) {
        this.leftPhilo = leftPhilo;
    }

    enter code here

    public void setRightPhilo(Philo rightPhilo) {
        this.rightPhilo = rightPhilo;
    }



    @Override
    public PhiloStatus call() throws Exception {

        if (leftPhilo.getStatus() == PhiloStatus.THINKING
                && rightPhilo.getStatus() == PhiloStatus.THINKING) {

            this.status =PhiloStatus.DINING;
            System.out.println("Dininig "+this);
            return PhiloStatus.DINING;

        }

        this.status =PhiloStatus.THINKING;
        System.out.println("Thinking "+this);
        return PhiloStatus.THINKING;
    }

    public PhiloStatus getStatus() {

        return status;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }

}
```

Starting point of the program

```
public class Start {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Philo[] philosophers = new Philo[5];


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
          philosophers[i] = new Philo(""+i);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
          philosophers[i].setLeftPhilo(philosophers[(i + 4) % 5]);
          philosophers[i].setRightPhilo(philosophers[(i + 1) % 5]);

          executorService.submit( philosophers[i]);

        }



    }

}
```

But seems like once Callable is finished executing , it returns the same result.

I doubt now that it might not be possible to solve this problem using Future?

Could anyone please shed a light on this.

Comment: I think the error is in the part where you actually use the Callable. Can you please post that code part?

Comment: The lifecycle of the callable is till it returns the result, while the lifecycle of the algorithm is much more than that. The philosopher must not complete execution by returning status.

Comment: @Narendra Pathai so solution is to use a Runnable and infinite loop within it?

Comment: Yes that's what I think would do the job. See the answer I have provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Philo implements Runnable{

   @Override
   public void run(){
       while(true){

           if(Thread.interrupted()){
               break;
           }

           //dining logic
       }

   }
}
```

The solution can be a loop which executes till someone interrupts the `Philosopher`.

Comment: Thanks. But then this solution become independent from Future though :(

Comment: Yes the problem does not have a return value, but is a long running task. Which by default does not match with Future.

Comment: I hear you. So Future is not a suitable construct for this problem.

Comment: Yes that's what I think.

Answer (score 1):

A Callable computes the result once, then returns the value *for this computation*. So if you want to compute something again, you need to run the Callable again.

```
void diningAttempt() {
  Future<PhiloStatus>[] results = new Future<PhiloStatus>[philosophers.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < philosophers.length; ++i) {
    results[i] = executor.submit(philosophers[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < philosophers.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(results[i].get());
  }
}
```

And then somewhere else:

```
while (dining) {
  diningAttempt();
}
```

As you can probably see, this is slightly different to what the “Dining Philosopher” problem actually describes, which is the problem of threads being able to do something *at any time*, as in this case you have separated dining attempts, which then most likely succeed all the time.

If you want those threads to actually lock, you need to give them the ability to run in parallel *all the time*, which means a Callable is not the correct way to simulate this issue. Nevertheless your attempt has a valuable lesson to learn: if you manage to put your work in separate batches like above, threads are much less likely to lock. And this is why the Executor has been invented in the first place.